# Referencing library/project written in .NetCore 2.0 to .net framework mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a question is it possible to reference .net core project to .net framework 4.6.1 MVC.

I tried to do it by adding standard references, but no luck there it just telling me that project target to .net core platform can not be referenced to .net framework one.

Anyone knows answer to that?

Comment: You should use a .net Standard library. That can be referenced by .net Core and .net Framework projects. See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Read also https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceANETCoreLibraryInWinFormsOrNETStandardExplained.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in fact, you can't do this but if you can migrate all the needed logic in a library targetting .net standard you will be able to reference it in each framework. And mainly this is the main goal of the .net standard.